# XCode : How to get resize view buttons in interface builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I opened an old project in Xcode 6 Version 6.0 (6A279r).

For certain .xib files IB is showing resize-view buttons as follows:
[image]

But, for certain .xib files IB is not showing resize-view buttons:
[image]

How can I enable the missing resize view buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, this was simple.

Just go to "Attributes Inspector" and select "Freeform" under size:

[image]