# How to resize xib file in xcode 6?

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I created new xib file in swift. I want to set custom size (in points) to it in the interface builder, but the size elements (height and width) are disabled.

How to resize it?

Remark: I need specific size of the xib, because I try to create custom Alert View.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are operating under a serious misconception. The size of the view in the *.xib* file has *nothing* to do with the size at which it will be shown when it loads. To set the size when it loads, set some property that affects the size at load time, such as `preferredContentSize`.

Comment: My code for creating a custom view that looks like an alert view might help you here: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7

Comment: I understand that. I want to set size of the view to be a specific width and height in points. I was confused by new IB in xcode 6.1 (yosemite). I used to it and I found that I need to remove size classes and to set size to `Freeform` and I am able to set values that I need. I will make 2 xibs for iPhone and iPad (I am not used to use size classes yet).

Comment: Actually @matt, I am using your code as example and in your code xib has smaller size already :).

Comment: @new2ios But that _still_ has nothing to do with the size that the view will be when the app runs!

Comment: I was curious about this as well- Isn't the whole point of having a GUI for building the interface to give you some general idea of what things might look like? I'm trying to lay out some things and having the Xib file the correct final size would help give me an idea as to how things are looking. Thanks for the tip, regardless. Cheers

Comment: @Hairgami_Master The _canvas_ is merely a design area. The _preview_ shows you how things will look at a particular size. What mediates between them? Autolayout!

Answer (score 6):

Although Matt is right that you cannot set the final size of a the main view of an IB file (we're talking about an IB file that only contains a view), you can resize the View in IB if you need to get an idea of how it will look like at run time. This is, of course, assuming you set the right dimensions at run time. But it definitely helps being able to get the right size you want by looking at it in IB and then getting the dimensions from there.

Just select the View, go to the attributes inspector:
Simulated Metrics -> Size : Freeform.

[Someone answered this already here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25403748/xcode-how-to-get-resize-view-buttons-in-interface-builder).